# iOS: Users experiencing crashes on certain iPad Devices

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

Some users are experiencing crashes on certain iPad devices and I am not sure how to handle the situation. I checked crashlytics and none of the crash appeared. I checked my iPad air and didn't notice any of the crashes. I am frustrated, I might have to go and buy an iPad mini or a new iPad device to make sure this is fixed. Any tips or suggestions to get around this?

Comment: You note that you don't have crash logs but do you have any additional information? "It crashed" won't let anyone here help you. That said, if any of these crash-users are technically savvy, you might be able to have them use Xcode or Apple Configurator to get to the _device_ console log to get additional insight into the actual error occurring. Finally, you note "certain devices" have the crash but only list one example of the device that doesn't crash. If you're more complete in describing what you do and which devices are known to fail, someone may spot a pattern you've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Crashlytics knolwdgebase](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/121064-why-don-t-i-see-data-from-my-first-crash-in-the-da).

> If you notice that you're suddenly missing some crash reports, we might be missing a dSYM that we need to process the crash.  For data fidelity reasons, we only display crashes that we can symbolicate.